# Compiling a cljs file to a javascript string using the cljs API

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm struggling a little with the cljs API.   I have a `.cljs` file containing a series of forms on my classpath and want to obtain the corresponding javascript as a string, without having to write to any kind of filesystem.  I can get it through the analyzer, but don't know how to get the javascript emitted:

```
(with-core-cljs nil (fn []
                        (analyze-file "us/quartyard/wat.cljs")
                        (println(all-ns)) ;; prints essentially what I expect.
                        (now what???)))
```

I've read the docs and it is by no means obvious what to call after `analyze-file`.

**Edit (adding more information):**

There is a function `cljs.compiler.api/emit` which return some js given an AST node.  But the only way I have found to get an AST node is to call `(analyze form)` where `form` is a single cljs form.

To analyze a complete file defining a namespace with many forms,  the only obvious way use to call `analyze-file`, which returns nothing and adds the AST for the namespace to the ambient compiler state.  But it's not clear how to get that AST back out.

For example:

```
(with-core-cljs nil (fn []
                        (analyze-file "us/quartyard/wat.cljs")
                        (emit (analyze (empty-env) '(println "ok"))))
```

emits a single line of js that prints "ok", but nothing from my file.

Meanwhile,

```
(with-core-cljs nil (fn []
                        (analyze-file "us/quartyard/wat.cljs")
                        (find-ns 'us.quartyard.wat)))
```

returns `nil`, rather than an AST for my namespace.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Try `(cljs.compiler.api/emit)`

Comment: @ClojureMostly:  That was my first thought, but I don't see how to make it work.  I've added additional context/explanation to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it this way:

`(cljs.build.api/compile {} "us/quartyard/wat.cljs")`